# How to Scale Fibers's object use XTK API

Tags: javascript, xtk, medical

There is a problem, the Fibers object can not automatic alignment with Volume and Mesh. Those files are come from the same source (one subject's DICOM file) so it should can be match together in default.

If only show the Fibers object, it can be put in the center of the view. But if show three object together, then Fibers object will be Shift!!!

So I try to use XTK API to fix this problem, I've tried X.fibers.transform, but there is no method can achieve it, I also tried X.fibers.scalars and X.fibers.points but still not work. Specifically in X.fibers.points I've tried to change the points value but I can't save back the value, there is a method get() can allow me to get the point value(Vertex coordinates), but there is no way can "set()" back the value when I have changed it.

Please tell me how to scale the Fibers!~ There is no way feasible by XTK API?

And here is my source code: http://goo.gl/Ttzc84
Demo Web: http://goo.gl/NP2eUo